# Remove WCF security

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I haven't worked with WCF much. And as fast as it came, it passed me by and I was on to webmethods and api stuff. So I'm tasked with removing WCF Security from this old service. There are so many settings in the config, that I'm a little miffed. I really don't have time to revisit old tech at the moment and would like a quick solution to just disable the security requirement. Is it as simple as setting security mode = "None"?

**service config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviors" name="QSService.QSSService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulQuality" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity"
          contract="QSSContracts.IQSService"/>
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpTransportSecurity"
          contract="QSSContracts.IQSService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WCFRestAuthentication/api/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpTransportSecurity" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulQuality">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None"
            serviceAuthorizationManagerType="xxx.xxx.Common.ADFSTokenHandling.xxxServiceAuthorizationManager, xxx.xxx.Common.ADFSTokenHandling"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**one of many client configs**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="ICOSService" address="https://dev-svc-cossecurity.xxxservices.com/COSSecurityService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_ICOSService"
        contract="COS.IService.ICOSService">
      </endpoint> 
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_ICOSService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None"
            serviceAuthorizationManagerType="xxx.xxx.Common.ADFSTokenHandling.xxxServiceAuthorizationManager, xxx.xxx.Common.ADFSTokenHandling"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Security mode in WCF cannot be started or turned off with one click.
Here are a few things you can look for to try setting safe mode:

1. Change the security mode.
2. Set the ClientCredentialType Property.
3. Change TransportWithMessageCredential.

The first two items are in your code and you can change them. You can also follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-set-the-security-mode) for further information